# The [usb] tag is not a game specific area of expertise - can we burn or merge it with [hardware]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request, burnination

The [usb](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/usb) tag is used on questions relating to issues to do with USB ports on consoles, or peripherals such as headphones that use the USB standard.

However, unlike other hardware types, such as [controllers](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/controllers), [mouse](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mouse)/[keyboard](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/keyboard) [graphics-card](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphics-card) (which has its own problems which I wont get into), it doesn't *specifically relate to a type of peripheral that could be used for gaming*.

Also:

- It isn't being followed (Not useful as a filter)
- Every question under the tag can stand on its own without it. (It doesn't disambiguate the question)
- It's a port & a format for transferring data & powering devices. The devices themselves are what we should be concerned about, not [usb](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/usb) specifically.

So, I'm all for nuking it from orbit (its the only way to be sure), but it could also find a new life as a synonym of [hardware](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hardware). Thoughts?

Comment: Let's just kill all those tags

Comment: @OrigamiRobot - graphics-card yes, mouse/keyboard meh, controllers no. controllers I think is a large enough field to deserve its own tag

Comment: I agree with @OrigamiRobot

Comment: @Robotnik A large field is not necessarily a reason for a tag.  Genres are large fields but we don't have tags for them.  A tag should represent an area of expertise.  Think of it this way.  How many people do you think subscribe to [tag:controllers]?

Comment: We allow questions about game specific hardware and utilities. It's right there on our [about](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/about) page. **However** we don't need a tag for every variation of a controller out there. Can you imagine? [logitech-gpro-920sx-gamepad], [revolution-sim-pro-joystick] etc. This is why the [controllers] tag exists. to logically group an area of expertise (troubleshooting controller & joystick issues) into one tag. Anyway that's another issue entirely, [lets keep focused](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NnP5iDKwuwk) on the [usb] tag in this meta.

Comment: @OrigamiRobot - also, 10 people subbed and 232 questions. I checked beforehand when researching for [usb]

Comment: Saying it doesn't need a tag is in no way saying the questions shouldn't be allowed.

Comment: @OrigamiRobot - Proving that they're allowed is a superset of 'they should be grouped together because...'. It seems [we've had this discussion before](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/7469/merge-request-xbox-controller-controllers), if you feel that strongly about it, make a meta. Also, [here's](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/1596/differences-between-controllers-and-peripherals) the post where meta decided on [controllers] over a broader [peripherals] tag.

Comment: someone with a usb related problem might not think of the word "hardware", so maybe it could be a synonym

Comment: how about stuff like [[tag:framerate]]? (closely related)

Comment: @3ventic I think that's getting rather far afield from the subject of this meta. (But, to answer, I believe framerate is a) a concern of especial interest to gamers and therefore b) an area of expertise game players have. Whether it needs a tag or not is debatable, but it's more likely to survive such a debate, I think.)

Comment: I am currently making a game where you have to shoot down bits of the USB Standard to stop hacks, so I suggest you keep it.

Comment: @JohnDoeSanta - When you release your game, we can re-jig the tag description to match, and only use it for questions about the game. (A tag cannot exist without a question, so it will simply be created the first time someone has a question about your game)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It isn't an area of our expertise, and it doesn't usefully categorise anything. The exception is that it seems to categorise external USB storage (sticks, drives), but that's not a useful category of expertise *here* – if it's actually a meaningful tag on a question, that's probably a sign that the *question* belongs on SuperUser or elsewhere.

[usb](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/usb) doesn't even have utility as a synonym, since none of its existing (and therefore, likely future) uses benefit from replacing it with something else like [hardware](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hardware).

I'm convinced. Please enter your nuclear armament authorisation codes, Mr. President.

Comment: An interesting game. The only winning move is... Not to play

Comment: Noone? wow that makes me feel old. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NHWjlCaIrQo

Comment: I swear, it's on my to-watch pile! I just don't get to see movies often.

Comment: @Robotnik I got it, I just didn't see the comment until just now. Also, you're not old compared to a lot of other site users. No-one in mid-20s gets to call themselves old.

Comment: [It is done](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QUAItQmq-LU)